# Normalization before data split in Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, non-linear-regression

I am trying to run a MLP regressor on my dataset with one hidden layer. I am doing a standardization of my data but I want to be clear as whether it matters if I do the standardization after or before splitting the dataset in Training and Test set. I want to know if there will be any difference in my prediction values if I carry out standardization before data split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. If mean and variance of the training and test set are different, standardization can lead to a different outcome.

That being said, a good training and test set should be similar enough so that the data points are distributed in a similar way, and post-split standardization should give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely do it before splitting.

Imagine having [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] as your inputs, which get split into [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10] for train and [6,8] for test.

It's immediately clear that min-max ranges, as well as the mean and standard deviation of both samples are completely different, so by applying standardization "post-split", you are completely scrambling the relationship between the values in the 1st and the 2nd set.